# AKS using Internal endpoint for communication

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops

I know we can set up application with internal or external ip address using load balancer. If I use external Ip address I can reserve it in Azure beforehand as public. Now my question is what if I don't want that ip address to be visible from outside the cluster ?

Configuration for internal ip address in kubernetes yaml would be:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: internal-app
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
spec:
  loadBalancerIP: 10.240.1.90
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    app: internal-app
```

Now I've read that the specified IP address must reside in the same subnet as the AKS cluster and must not already be assigned to a resource.

If I have ip address for my aks agentpool set up as X.X.0.0/16 and I use for example X.X.0.1 as Ip address for my internal load balancer I'm getting error: 'Private IP address is in reserved subnet range'

I see I also have something like internal endpoints in AKS. Can those be used for internal application-to-application communication ?

I'm just looking for any way for my apps to talk with each other internally with out exposing them to outside world. Also I'd like for that to be repeatable that means that something like dynamic ip addresses wouldn't be too good. I need the set up to be repeatable so I don't have to change all of the apps internal settings every time Ip address changes accidentally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest solution is just to use a service of type ClusterIP. it would create a virtual IP address inside the cluster that your apps can use to reach each other. You can also use the dns name of the service to reach it:

```
service-name.namespace.svc.cluster.local
```

from any pod inside kubernetes. either of these ways you dont have to care about ip addresses at all, kubernetes manages them

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is the dns name autoassigned or can we specify it somehow in yaml definition ? Setup will be where few apps will be exposed to outside world but most of backend applications should not be. Also just now I tried adress from different scope for internal load balancer and it worked. I guess some adresses are reserved and some are not but I have no way of telling which

Comment: like i specified in the answer dns name is always `service-name.namespace.svc.cluster.local`. first 3 and the last 1 ip address is reserved out of any subnet you provision in Azure, this is not related to AKS at all

Comment: I tried using the dns name but all I'm getting while trying to test access from console is 'Could not resolve host'. Dns I'm trying: my-service-name.default.svc.cluster.local. So I changed service-name part and namespace which according to kubectl is 'default'. Should I change anything else ? I wasn't able to find any information in the documentation about the dns naming convention you provided.

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#dns. service name should be `internal-app` in your case.